# SQL Server (2012, 2014, 2017) query to figure out host OS

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows

I'm trying to figure out what query will get the host OS, whether if it's a Linux or Windows OS.

Querying `sys.dm_os_host_info` seems to get the results I need but that table doesn't seem to exist on SQL Server < 2017.

Comment: `dm_os_host_info` was added with 2017, as SQL Server was made available on both Windows and Linux with that Version.

Comment: `dm_os_host_info` also doesn't work on Azure. Are you likely to be using an Azure SQL Database as well?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the heads up, maybe in the future, so that's good information to have.

Comment: Additionally, `SELECT @@VERSION` will include the host OS

Comment: Almost what I'm looking for! I might have to do some parsing to get this info, would be great if there's some other way to find this information through a query.